# What is the maximum number of sockets that select() can handle in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

`select()` can handle 64 sockets by default, I can change this limit by overriding the `FD_SETSIZE` constant at compile time. But what is the maximum number that `FD_SETSIZE` can take?

Also should I really use `select()` under Windows, or should I use `WSAEventSelect()`? (not sure if `WSAEventSelect()` allows for more than 64 sockets though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN did not specific the upper limit for `FD_SETSIZE`. However there are number of factor affect the practical limit.

1. Concurrent connection limit (system-wise), which is about 1000~4000 on general workstation.
2. Performance. Windows's `select()` is implemented really badly that you should consider using `WSAAsyncSelect()` and completion port for more than thousand sockets.

Comment: What is the "Concurrent connection limit"? You mean I can only have a maximum of 4000 connected sockets at one time! Also does `WSAAsyncSelect()` and IOCP used together or I should choose one of them?

Comment: Generally, normal Windows without serious tweak can only handle one to few thousand simultaneous connections at a time, and start returning connection fail.

Comment: So how am I supposed to handle 8000 client connections?!

Comment: Google it. http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html  Or otherwise use Linux/BSD which are designed for higher capacity.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about ephemeral ports, and those only exists on the client side. I mean each client socket must listen to a unique port. While on the server side, all server sockets listen to the same port. So on the server side I think the sockets maximum number is much higher than that.

Comment: I should have said that I am talking about sockets on the server side, and not sockets on the client side (which each have a unique source port).

Comment: No. Windows has other limits that prevent you making more connections even on the same local port. Read the link above, like the TCB table size and other tweaks.

Comment: Something is not right, I will create a simple test to see how many connections I can get and report the results :-)

Comment: JFYI, I think it depends on the window version. Without tweaks, my test with windows 7 Home capped at 4k connections, while windows 8.1 I can goes for 100k, although throughput is insanely slow (ping-pong test, window `select` give 35k packet/seconds, whereas linux `epoll` give 150k, per giga-bit NIC, 1024 bytes payload). Look forward to your results.

Comment: I put the client on 5 VBox Windows XP SP2 (each client creates 3500 connections), and connected to my Windows 7 Ultimate machine, I got all of the connections successfully (17500 connections).

Answer (score 0):

1. The maximum number of sockets depends upon underlying WinSock Service Provider (WinSock itself is just the interface wrapper). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169(v=vs.85).aspx
2. WSAEventSelect() has some additional capabilities over select(), but FD_SETSIZE is handled by both functions just the same.

Comment: If you have a reference for the 2nd claim, please share it. Thanks!

Comment: `FD_SETSIZE` isn't handled by [`WSAEventSelect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at all. This API only handles one socket, not a set.